# javascript bridge for iOS

Tags: javascript

I am using a javascript bridge to communicate between a hybrid web app and iOS using a webView.

my question is how to get the function ios_getUserID() from within the script to put a value to the variable UserID that exists above the javascript bridge function.

I have a web page and connected to it is a script js file. scripts.js looks like this:

```
var userID="";

//javascript ios bridge


window.onerror = function(err) {
    log('window.onerror: ' + err)
}

function connectWebViewJavascriptBridge(callback) {
    if (window.WebViewJavascriptBridge) {
        callback(WebViewJavascriptBridge)
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('WebViewJavascriptBridgeReady', function()     {
                                  callback(WebViewJavascriptBridge)
                                  }, false)
    }
 }

connectWebViewJavascriptBridge(function(bridge) {
                               var uniqueId = 1
                               function log(message, data) {
                               var log = document.getElementById('log')
                               var el = document.createElement('div')
                               el.className = 'logLine'
                               el.innerHTML = uniqueId++ + '. ' + message + ':<br/>' + JSON.stringify(data)
                               if (log.children.length) { log.insertBefore(el, log.children[0]) }
                               else { log.appendChild(el) }
                               }
                               bridge.init(function(message, responseCallback) {
                                           log('JS got a message', message)
                                           var data = { 'Javascript   Responds':'Weeeeeeee!' }
                                           log('JS responding with', data)
                                           responseCallback(data)
                                           })

                              bridge.registerHandler('testJavascriptHandler', function(data, responseCallback)   {
                                                      log('ObjC called   testJavascriptHandler with', data)
                                                      var responseData = {   'Javascript Says':'Right back atcha!' }
                                                      log('JS responding   with', responseData)
                                                     responseCallback(responseData)
                                                           })


                               bridge.registerHandler('softUserID',   function(data, responseCallback) {
                                                      log('softUserID ObjC    called testJavascriptHandler with', data)



                                                      alert(data.userID);


                                                      var responseData = { 'Javascript Says':'super!' }
                                                      log('JS responding  with', responseData)
                                                     responseCallback(responseData)
                                                      })



                               ios_getUserID = function(){

                                var obj = '{"action" : "getUserID"}';

                               //alert("crossing bridge");
                               var data = obj
                               log('JS sending message', data)
                               bridge.send(data, function(responseData) {
                                          log('JS got response', responseData)
                                           alert(responseData);
                                           })
                               }



                               });
```

Comment: It would be ok if you can format the JS code.